# What is the proper usage of "however" and where is it placed?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, discourse-markers, however-placement

What is the correct usage of *however;* and *however*?

> I sometimes find myself not really checking my email on a daily basis
>   but, **I do however;** find this to be very helpful to keep up with what's
>   going on. Now that I am in school I will make sure that I check
>   everyday just to make sure that I stay on top of my work and
>   schooling.

Comment: related [Should there always be a comma after "therefore", "however" etc.?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/should-there-always-be-a-comma-after-therefore-however-etc) and [Use of a semicolon before and comma after "however"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104864/use-of-a-semicolon-before-and-comma-after-however)

Comment: First, distinguish the contrastive pragmatic marker usage from the quantifier usage (However hard I try, I don't seem able to cope). Then check the previous threads.

Comment: duplicate of "rule of thumb for 'however' in the middle of the sentence?" & certainly answered there, as Mari-Lou says.