# Does the word "therefore" always require a comma if it is in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if the following sentence is correct. My primary question revolves around the word "therefore" and whether or not it requires a comma.

> Understanding why ex-prisoners renew their criminal involvement is therefore an important social issue for scholars, decision makers, and corrections officials.

Comment: I think the answer is here - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/should-there-always-be-a-comma-after-therefore-however-etc